# Jade, для чего это нужно?

Tags: препроцессор

Для чего нужен препроцессор?

Не только *Jade*, но и *Sass*, *Less*, и прочие.  Неужели *Emmet* не справляется со своей задачей?
Ведь чтобы пользоваться этими плюшками столько требуется устанавливать лишнего, ненужного.

Установить ещё мало, даже чтобы что-то получилось нужна ещё и компиляция, неужели это удобнее чем нажать пальцем три клавиши?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основные плюсы:

- Переменные
- Вложенность
- Миксины, импорты и т.п

Почитайе хороший пост на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/214143/).

Comment: а для чего вообще эти переменные и прочее ?

Comment: @Geyan вы разработчик? Смотрите, пришел клиент он хочет быстро сделать стартап. Мы берем bootstrap / foundation или что-то в таком роде и его быстро кастомизируем под свои нужды через переменные и получается продукт красивый и стабильный. Потом он берет дизайнера и тот настраивает цвета и мы легко их меняем с помощью переменных. А не как дауны ходим по файлам и меняем руками.

Comment: хорошее объяснение , но я так понимаю это для крупных проектов ?я не профи - но иногда делаю заказы но не крупные

Comment: @Geyan для любых видов продукта, клиент хочет видеть результат как можно раньше + html responsive и чтобы все красиво было и ровно, то лучше использовать готовые решения которые хорошо дружат с препроцессорами и позволяют вам быстро писать софт.

Comment: ну да , по другому и быть не может это я давно понял , так же и на фрилансе биржах только и требуют это, но а если это делать вез fundation или bootstrap но на своей технике без препроцессоров это возброняется ?

Answer (score 4):

Вы смешали в кучу три разных вещи. Jade - это шаблонизатор для ноды. sass и less - это генераторы для css (или как их называют по модному - препроцессоры), а emmet - это плугин для редактора. jade и emmet не являются препроцессорами.

Почему появились препроцессоры? все просто. Современные браузеры развиваются быстро и новые возможности появляются часто. Но не всегда эти возможности появляются во всех браузерах одновременно и одинаково. Препроцессоры как раз позволяют скрыть эти особенности.

Когда то давно, очень сложной задачей было сделать таблицу с линиями в один пиксель шириной и скругленными краями. Особенно много проблем было в IE5.5 (да, я и IE3/IE4 видел). В современном мире с препроцессорами эта задача решилась бы просто - для препроцессора создали бы нужный стиль, а сам препроцессор для нужного набора браузеров сгенерирует правильный css.

Или вторая задача - к примеру, хочется, что бы один элемент был на 10 пикселей шире другого, но если тот больше 100, то на 20. На классическом css это, насколько мне известно, не решается. Нужно применять js. А less умеет при компиляции считать арифметические выражения и все сделает сам.

Может ли Emmet в этом всем помочь? нет. Он помогает редактировать. Но если завтра выйдет ещё один браузер с поддержкой HTML100500, где будет куча новых функций, sass/less допишут плагины и будут генерировать css под них. Создатели шаблонизатора jade поступят где то также. А пользователям emmet придется править все вручную.

Comment: вот именно , я сравнил все css препроцессоры и html препроцессоры , в том и вопрос - что быстрее , сделать на emmet или zencoding или эти не нужные Плюшки ?

Comment: jade же вроде html препроцессор ?

Comment: а почему Вы рассматриваете только одно против другого, а не их работу вместе?

Но что быстрее? а это зависит от Вас. Возможно, Вы бог клавиатуры и энциклопедия по всем особенностям css в голове. Тогда и emmet не нужен, не говоря о sass/less. Jade - это шаблонизатор. Да, оно пересекается немного с препроцессором, но все таки немного различные вещи.

Comment: ну css3 вроде знаю и применяю  (если по детскому сказать) но .. я в ступоре , ну к примеру что бы (по тупому сказать) слепить html шаблон для openCard у меня уходит не более одного часа и ещё два или три для адаптации , может быть с огрехами но по крайней мере на iphone и в ie6-12 всё выглядело нормально (на данный момент нету примеров ) и полностью готовый продукт после тестирования отдавался через сутки , через препроцессоры это было бы быстрее ?

Comment: @Geyan конечно быстрее, и приятнее. Sass — это метаязык на основе CSS, используемый, чтобы сделать описание стиля документа более чистым и структурированным; он обладает большими возможностями в сравнении с простым CSS. Sass предлагает более доступный и изящный синтаксис для CSS, а также, различные полезные инструменты для создания таблиц стилей, которые будет легко поддерживать в дальнейшем.

Comment: лан теперя вопрос уже от тупого user : как им начать пользоваться ? учить не надо а просто ссылку на хороший мануал